# Custom Post Type Display start on 5th array

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I added in 10 custom post . i wanted to display 5-10 number post in my template file. so please give me suggestion for that.

```
$args_team = array(
    'post_type' => 'team',
    'posts_per_page' => 4
);
$query_team = new WP_Query( $args_team );
if($query_team->have_posts()) : while($query_team->have_posts()) : 
     $query_team->the_post();
     //content here
endwhile; endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have set a counter for it to display from 5-10 from your custom post type.

To achieve this, set a variable $i = 1 at the beginning of the loop

```
$i = 1;
$args_team = array(
            'post_type' => 'team',
            'posts_per_page' => -1
            );
            $query_team = new WP_Query( $args_team );
            if($query_team->have_posts()) : while($query_team->have_posts()) : $query_team->the_post();
                if ($i >= 5 && $i <= 10){
                    // some of your code here
                }
            $i++;
            endwhile;
            endif;
```

Here you loop every post of the post type and if it is between 5 and 10 which means 6 posts have to show in the page. If you dont want 5 and 10 to be included just remove the "=" sign in the if statement inside the while loop.

Hope this works for you

Thank You